# Crontab and Python | Won't write CSV

Tags: python, csv, cron

I've got a very simple python program that generates a csv. From the command line when I execute

```
python test.py
```

I have no issues. A CSV is generated. However, when I runs through a crontab I get notification that it ran successfully but there is no CSV.

Not sure what I need to change

**test.py**

```
def writeCSV():
    import csv
    print 'Cron Started'

    with open('testout.csv', 'wb') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
        writer.writerow('test')

    print 'Cron Complete'


writeCSV()
```

**Crontab -l**

```
*/1 * * * * python /Users/Me/Desktop/test.py
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't specify the path as an absolute path, the file will be generated in the home directory.

Check your home directory.

Or if you want to generate the file in the specific directory, specify the path as absolute path, or use `cd` command before execute the python  command.

Comment: is /Users/Me/Desktop/test.py not an absolute path?

How should my cronjob look?

Comment: You need to use an absolute path in your python script when opening the file! What you could also do is this: `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` - that will change the working directory to the directory where the file is located. (you need to `import os` for it to work)

Comment: @user3195487, I mean the path in the script.

Comment: So at the end of the script I need to add:

os.chdir(/Users/ME/Desktop(import.py) 

Is that right?

Comment: @user3195487, No, you should put that line at the beginning of the script (after the shebang line): `import os; os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))`